# NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have been trying to get data from api in json format and put it in a listView. I can get the data just fine and print it in the console but it wont show in the list. Currently getting an error

> NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.

This comes when I try to decode the json. Right now Im trying this with

```
      data = json.decode(response.body.toString()).cast<products>();
```

and have also tried the following but both give same error.

```
//Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
  //data = map["dataKey"];
```

Below is my main code as well as the custom class for the data.

class MyAppState extends State {
List data;

```
Future callApi(String category) async{
  String username = '400107';
  String password = 'rR86zH';
  String basicAuth =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
  print(basicAuth);

  var url = Uri.parse("https://www.floristone.com/api/rest/flowershop/getproducts?category=" + category);
  Response response = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});

  data = json.decode(response.body.toString()).cast<products>();


  //Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
  //data = map["dataKey"];

  print(data);
}
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Flowers"),
    ),
    body: Column(children: [
      Expanded(
          child: data == null
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){

                products item = data[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(item.name),
                  subtitle: Text(item.description),
            );
          }),
      ),



    ],),
  ),

  );
}
}
```

Class below

```
class products {
 double price;
 String dimension;
 String name;
 String large;
 String description;
 String small;
 String code;

 products(
     {this.price,
      this.dimension,
    this.name,
    this.large,
    this.description,
    this.small,
    this.code});

 products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
price = json['price'];
dimension = json['dimension'];
name = json['name'];
large = json['large'];
description = json['description'];
small = json['small'];
code = json['code'];
 }

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
data['price'] = this.price;
data['dimension'] = this.dimension;
data['name'] = this.name;
data['large'] = this.large;
data['description'] = this.description;
data['small'] = this.small;
data['code'] = this.code;
return data;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

.cast<String,dynamic>();
See also https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Map/cast.html

Usually it's better to use Map<String,String>.from(oldMap) instead of cast<...>(...)

Comment: I have tried that also but it still gives me an error: Unhandled Exception: type 'CastMap<String, dynamic, String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<products>'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should named the class in UpperCamelCase as suggested in the [style guide](https://app.quicktype.io/).

In order to convert a JSON object, you can simply use the `fromJson()` method being defined.

```dart
final product = Products.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

In this case I'm assuming `response.body` is in `String` format. If it's already in `Map<String, dynamic>` format, you can just do this:

```dart
final product = Products.fromJson(response.body);
```